# Unable to find topsearch template file in magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9

I am making a custom theme from scratch in magento using bootstrap, i have already [raised a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36152342/should-i-customize-existing-magento-css-or-i-should-include-bootstrap-and-use-th) for that purpose i have received really helpful answers.

Now i am on my way to make theme, but currently i am stuck with finding the template .phtml file for top search bar in default theme. I have already searched base theme and google but did not reached anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find any template file from

->Go to **admin->system->configuration**.

-> Switch to the store view on the top left to your current website or store view.

-> Go to Developer on the bottom left under ADVANCED

->Under the Debug tab of the same Developer config page you will see a new option appear that will allow you to turn on/off template path hints.

Search Form File:

**app/design/frontend/Your-Package/Your-Theme/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml**

In default RWD theme

**app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml**

Comment: Thank you so much.
I've found the template here `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml` and thanx for the overall final solution to find template every time.

Answer (score 0):

Just find `form.mini.phtml` on this location:

> app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalogsearch

For modify it copy it on your theme like:

> app\design\frontend\theme_package\your_theme\template\catalogsearch

Hope it will help you.